# I'm trying to understand a piece of code used with the codeigniter framework

Tags: codeigniter

Can someone explain what is happening here:

```
<?= isset($user) ? set_value('val',$this->form_validation->val) : set_value('val'); ?>
```

why is there a '=' sign in right after the opening php tag.

Comment: `<?=` is short variant for `echo`. Just print result of set_value('val')

Comment: OH! didn't know that, thanks}. Now what does the rest mean?

Comment: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html?highlight=set_value#set_value

Comment: what are the conditionals called when they use " ? : "

Comment: If $user exists, print validated value of `<input name="val" value="" >`, otherwise just print `<input name="val" value >`

Comment: Ternary operator (?:) is short variant for if..else  http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary